# Почему не корректно работает калькулятор?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал калькулятор, вроде все просто, но почему то не работает

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
 var machines = [
  "Saeco Hd 8745",
  "Delonghi 3000 B",
  "Saeco HD 8753",
  "Saeco HD 8920",
  "Saeco Aulika TOP",
  "Saeco Aulika MID",
  "Индивидуальное предложение, оставьте заявку, с вами свяжется менеджер",
  "Извините, ничего не найдено"
 ];
 var pcis = $('#cups-per-month').val();
 var kgs = $('#cons-per-month2').val();
 var cappuccino = $('#additional-option3').is(":checked");
 var output = (kgs <= 2 && pcis <= 5 && cappuccino == false) ? machines[0] :
    (kgs >= 3 && kgs <= 4 && pcis >= 6 && pcis <= 14 && cappuccino == false) ? machines[1] :
    (kgs == 5 && pcis >= 15 && pcis <= 19 && cappuccino == false) ? machines[1] :
    (kgs >= 6 && kgs <= 9 && pcis >= 20 && pcis <= 40 && cappuccino == true) ? machines[2] :
    (kgs >= 10 && kgs <= 15 && pcis >= 41 && pcis <= 60 && cappuccino == true) ? machines[3] + machines[4] + machines[5] :
    (kgs >= 16 && pcis >= 61 && cappuccino == true) ? machines[6] :
 machines[7];

 alert(output);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
 <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" value="1" id="#cups-per-month" name="pcis">
 <input type="number" min="1" max="9999" value="1" id="#cons-per-month2" name="kgs">
 <input class="custom-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="additional-option3" autocomplete="off"/>
 <button type="button" class="btn">Подобрать</button>
</form>
```

Comment: т.е. условия:
если kgs меньше 2, pcis меньше 5 и чекбокс убран - вывести 1
если kgs от 3 до 4, pcis от 6 до 14 и чекбокс убран - вывести 2
если kgs 5, pcis от 15 до 19 и чекбокс убран - вывести 2
если kgs от 6 до 9, pcis от 20 до 40 и чекбокс стоит - вывести 3
ну и так далее

Comment: Перепишите это хотя бы на более менее адекватный if/else, например сгруппировав по cappuccino == false и cappuccino == true, а потом продолжая дальше улучшать, избавився от магических чисел и т.д.

Comment: И да, получаете вы значения в виде строк, а проверяете числа.

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте Ваш html, Вы пытаетесь считать id `#cups-per-month`, а в коде у Вас `id="#cups-per-month"` Лишние символы `#`! id указываются без них.